# Retrieving calendar information from a mailbox with a special character in its primary e-mail address

Tags: c#, calendar, exchangewebservices

I've been writing code to retrieve calendar info from a room mailbox using Exchange Web Services. I'm able to successfully retrieve info from room mailboxes and user mailboxes alike, but I seem to have hit a snag. My theory is that it has to do with the ampersand in the address... I can confirm that this is the primary address of the room mailbox.  I've also made sure that I can access the calendar from outlook.

Here's my code which, once again, works really well on other mailboxes but fails with this one:

```
            EmailAddressType mailbox = new EmailAddressType();
            mailbox.EmailAddress = "r&d@somecompany.org";
            DistinguishedFolderIdType[] parentFolderId = new DistinguishedFolderIdType[1];
            parentFolderId[0] = new DistinguishedFolderIdType { Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.calendar, Mailbox = mailbox };
```

Has anyone experienced problems of this kind before? Any chance you might be able to nudge me in the right direction? Any help appreciated!

TIA,
Rick.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right.  Try replacing it with `&amp;`

Explanation: Since this is going across a Web Service, it's probably getting parsed into XML at some point, and the `&` character is reserved.  So you need to use `&amp;` any time you want to use `&` in a string.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Garrison. I've given that a shot but unfortunately it did not work. I've also tried the Uri.EscapeDataString and Uri.EscapeUriString methods, but nothing doing either :(

Comment: Using Fiddler, I took a look at the request my service sends EWS:

"...<Mailbox><EmailAddress>R&amp;D@somecompany.org</EmailAddress></Mailbox>..." 

If I remove the escaping, I get: 

"...<Mailbox><EmailAddress>R&D@somecompany.org</EmailAddress></Mailbox>..." 

But this time, the response I get is: 
"The specified folder could not be found in the store." 

Am I mistaken in thinking that this could actually an issue with the configuration of this specific resource mailbox, then?

Comment: I have zero experience with Exchange Web Services, I was just making a stab in the dark suggestion with the `&amp;` thing, since I'd run into it in the past.  I wish I could offer more.  Sorry.

Comment: Hey no problem, thanks for the suggestion! I figured it out in the end, the problem had to do with permissions. Also learned a thing or two about EWS, quite enlightening.

Comment: Well, post your fix as an answer so the next person who runs into the issue will find it here.  :-)